# Photo mosaic web application. KD-tree

Tags: php, language-agnostic, kdtree

Last month I have been working on a photomosaic website. I build everything in PHP and I got it working great. The only thing I don’t like is the execution time. This is too long I think because of a linear compare search.  So I have been asking around how to improve my search times and most people pointed me in to the direction of the KD-tree which will make k-nearest neighbor a lot quicker.

So I have been looking in to the KD-tree and I understand how to construct such a tree manually. Now I want to code this of course, I could only find libraries for C++ and java. Since I’m only familiar with PHP I’ve been trying to make it myself but this isn’t as easy as I thought it would be.

•   A problem I’m facing is how to store everything. When I get the first array with all points in it I’ll spit it in to 3 pieces. Left branch, node and right branch. Of course I will do the same with the left branch until I can’t split anymore ,of course I cycle through the axes (XYZ). But how do I store the all right branches do I leave them in an array? Or do I compute them again when I am ready to use them?

•   Another thing I was wondering is why is there no PHP KD-tree script is it because PHP is not the right language for this job?

This is what I have got so far.

This function computes random colors (RGB) Which I use to test the rest.

```
<?php
function randomiser($number){

    if($number <= 0){ 
        echo 'Error: The input of randomiser() is less than or equal to zero !!';
        return FALSE;         
    }else{ 
        $R = array();
        $G = array();
        $B = array();

        for($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++){
            $r = rand(1, 255);
            $g = rand(1, 255);
            $b = rand(1, 255);

            $rgb['pic ' . $x]['R'] = $r;
            $rgb['pic ' . $x]['G'] = $g;
            $rgb['pic ' . $x]['B'] = $b;    
        }  
    }
return $rgb;
}
?>
```

This function sort the multidimensional array on a specific key (default is R)

```
<?php
function sorter(&$array, $key = 'R'){

    if(!is_array($array)){ 
        echo 'Error: The input of sorter() is not an array !!<br>';
        return FALSE;         
    }else{ 
        uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($key){
            return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
        }); 
    }
}
?>
```

This class splits the array in to a left branch, node and right branch.

```
<?php
class splitting {

    public $left;
    public $node;
    public $right;

    function __construct($array){

        if(!is_array($array)){ 
            echo 'Error: The input of splitter() is not an array !!<br>';
            return FALSE;         
        }else{ 
            $number = count($array);
            $median = round($number / 2) - 1; 

            $this->left = array_slice($array, 0, $median);
            $this->node = array_slice($array, $median, 1);
            $this->right = array_slice($array, $median+1);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to store pointer to the tree  in the $left and $right variables not an array or any variable you need to work with. I would also look into a r-tree if a kd-tree is too complicated. A r-tree splits the plane into  4 edges i.e. in true 2 euklidian dimension and a kd-tree is just a binary tree.
   Then you need a variable $payload or something to backup the median.
2. No. You can find also php tree example. Here is an example: http://blog.sandfox.co.uk/2012/09/10/php-kdtree/. You can also look for my kart-trie implementation in php. It uses also OO and node and edges class. Here is a script to pack lightmaps into a kd-tree from http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html.

   ```
    struct Node
   {
        Node* child[2]
        Rectangle rc
         int imageID
    }

   Node* Node::Insert(const Image& img)
         if we're not a leaf then
         (try inserting into first child)
          newNode = child[0]->Insert( img )
         if newNode != NULL return newNode

    (no room, insert into second)
         return child[1]->Insert( img )
     else
   (if there's already a lightmap here, return)
   if imageID != NULL return NULL

   (if we're too small, return)
   if img doesn't fit in pnode->rect
       return NULL

   (if we're just right, accept)
   if img fits perfectly in pnode->rect
       return pnode

   (otherwise, gotta split this node and create some kids)
   pnode->child[0] = new Node
   pnode->child[1] = new Node

   (decide which way to split)
   dw = rc.width - img.width
   dh = rc.height - img.height

   if dw > dh then
       child[0]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top, 
                                  rc.left+width-1, rc.bottom)
       child[1]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left+width, rc.top, 
                                  rc.right, rc.bottom)
   else
       child[0]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top, 
                                  rc.right, rc.top+height-1)
       child[1]->rect = Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top+height, 
                                  rc.right, rc.bottom)

   (insert into first child we created)
   return Insert( img, pnode->child[0] )
   ```